# Is the "voir à + infinitif" construction confined to the colloquial expression "Faudrait voir à + infinitif"?

Tags: expressions, usage

I just said in conversation:

> **Faudrait voir à** pas donner l’impression d’être pingre, il n'y aura pas de deuxième chance.

... and have realised that I cannot think of other phrases where I can use the  "voir à + infinitif" construction. After all, you wouldn't say, for instance:

> On **devrait voir à** pas donner l’impression d’être pingre, ...

... even though its intended meaning is virtually the same as the first sentence.

I wonder if there are other expressions where the  "voir à + infinitif" construction works? Or is "Faudrait voir à + infinitif" the only one?

Comment: What about "Il faudrait aller faire à manger" or "Il faudrait faire à manger"? They look quite similar

Comment: @Nathan Hi. Ce n’est pas ce sur quoi porte ma question ! :) Pas la moindre trace de la phrase "voir à + infinitif".

Comment: The only reason that "faudrait voir à" has a colloquialness to it is the suppressed impersonal pronoun. I'm not sure if other verbs show the same evolution toward an almost particle syntactic construction: the "y" in *il y avoir* merges into the jod from the reduced *il* so it's impossible to tell if the pronouns drops in *y'a quà*, but the French-Canadian [*m'a*](http://www.wikebec.org/ma/definition/) may be an example?

Answer (score 2):

The [OQLF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2238) cite these sentences, which is close to the colloquial *faudrait voir* :

> - Il **faut voir à** faire réparer la voiture.

The [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/voir) has:

> B. − Voir à + inf. Veiller à, songer à; faire en sorte de. Si vous ne tenez pas à cette fille, pourquoi exposer ainsi votre vie? − Parce que je tiens encore moins à ma vie qu'à elle; mais brisons là-dessus. **Je vais voir à** finir gaiement la journée (Karr, Sous tilleuls, 1832, p. 182). Il est effectif, monsieur, que je suis très susceptible de confondre Arbois de Carthage avec Proclès de Jubainville. **Je verrai** plus tard **à** combler ces lacunes. Pour le moment, je désirerais savoir où nous sommes (Benoit, Atlant., 1919, p. 131).

Both TLFi ones seem slightly outdated to me.

Another sentence from *Les voyages faits par le sieur D.B. aux îles Dauphine ou Madagascar, et Bourbon, ou Mascarenne* (1674) is:

> Le lendemain 8, nous mîmes notre chaloupe dehors, pour aller à terre, **afin de voir à faire** de l'eau et du bois.

Here is a [current way](http://forums.phpbb-fr.com/support-utilisation-phpbb3/sujet195070.html) to use *voir à* where it doesn't follow *falloir*:

> *Donc si ton hébergeur dit que tu surcharges leur serveur MySQL, il serait peut-être judicieux **de voir à changer** d'hébergeur.*

Comment: The TLFi also has a dedicated paragraph for "Faudrait voir à" which is tagged as informal ("populaire"). Moreover, the current way of using "voir à" seems to stick with "songer à" (to consider) offered by the TLFi.

Answer (score -1):

Dire : "Faudrait voir à pas donner l’impression d’être pingre" n'est pas correct. Il faut dire : "Il faudrait voir à ne pas donner l'impression ...." car "voir à pas" est du langage populaire.